# Refreshing/reloading jquery actions after injecting HTML via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have this function:

```
$(function() {
   $("ul#autocomplete_groups").on('click', 'li', (function() {
     // do stuff
     var id = this.id;
     var gid = $("#add_group_members_form_gid").val();
     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       aysnc: true,
       url: '/cgi/script.pl',
       data: "action=add_group_member&voter_id=" + id + "&gid=" + gid,
       success: function(res) {
         $('#div_group_member_list_' + gid).parent().html(res);
         $.growl(
           {title:"Update successful", message:"Person added to group", duration:500, size: 'small' }
         );
       },
     });
   }))
});
```

The purpose of this function is to provide an autocomplete menu. When a user clicks on an item, it triggers a refresh of the section of the page, `#div_group_member_list_#`, where "#" is the section number of the page that gets changed.

This all works fine.

However, the buttons in the HTML returned by the ajax call which have jquery functions associated with them no longer work. Here's a sample of what one of those buttons look like:

```
<a href="#" class="remove_from_group ui-btn ui-btn-inline" gid="1" vid="85386">Remove</a>
```

And here's the action associated with that button:

```
$(function() {
  $(".remove_from_group").on('click', (function() {
    var vid = $( this ).attr( 'vid');
    var gid = $( this ).attr( 'gid');
    row = $(this).parent().parent();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      aysnc: true,
      url: '/cgi/script.pl',
      data: "action=remove_from_group&vid=" + vid + "&gid=" + gid,
      success: function(res) {
        // do stuff
        $.growl(
          {title:"Update successful", message:"Member removed from group", duration:500, size: 'small' }
        );
      },
    });
  }))
});
```

These buttons work perfectly prior to performing the ajax call via the first function but are completely unresponsive afterward.

I've looked at other answers to this problem but couldn't figure it out. I need something specific to my problem as I'm new to jquery and ajax. Thanks!

Comment: gotta use live() https://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$(document).on('click', ".remove_from_group", function() {...
```

Instead of this

```
$(".remove_from_group").on('click', (function() {...
```

Attaching it to the document allows the event to fire on elements that haven't been added to the dom yet